# How to use HTTPARTY to parse JSON api call from LinkedIN

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, linkedin-api, httparty

I'm using gem 'httparty' on my Rails 4 app and I'm a bit confused on the actual location and syntax of where to put the the lines of code that I've been reading. As of right now, it's in my controller and I'm trying to call it through the view which is connected to my controller via routes. Here is my controller below.

```
require 'httparty'

class StuffsController < ApplicationController

  def index 
    count = JSON.parse(url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' + url + '&format=json'
    count = JSON.parse(HTTParty.get(url).body)["count"] 
  end
end
```

I read this documentation from http://www.techhoppers.com/blog/ruby-on-rails/how-to-parse-the-json-api-call-with-httpparty-in-ruby-on-rails/#comment-7 and I would like to know where I'm supposed to put these two lines of code.

```
 response = HTTParty.get("http://example.com/call/httparty")
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so what do you want to do with `count`? show it in a template?

Comment: yes I would like to show it in a template.

Comment: use an ivar like `@count` in the controller and the view

Comment: To me this question is clear. You wanted to ask if we've to put the code of httParty module class in file inside project/lib/ directory or elsewhere like on the controller in your case. Am I right?

Comment: yes @marvindanig that was what was asking over a year ago. lol but nobody got my question.

Comment: This is actually a reason why I do not like StackOverFlow anymore. Not that its value has diminished,  in fact some Q&A up here are lifesavers for developers out there, but lately it seems that the intent is totally not to go in the direction of fixing a question if they did not understand it.  If those few good men don't see what the question was about in the first sweep "exactly through their lens" it is doomed to irrelevance. Unfortunate and helpless. BTW did you get to an answer that can clear this doubt for others?